Fourier transform of convolution of a function in $L^1$ and a function in $L^p$
While reading the book of Linares and Ponce, "Introduction to Nonlinear Dispersive Equations", I struggled doing this exercise on the first chapter:
If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$ and $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$, for $1 \leq p \leq 2$,  then:
\begin{equation} 
    \widehat{f\ast g}(\xi) = \widehat{f}(\xi) \widehat{g}(\xi)
\end{equation}
I know this identity is obviously true for some class of functions, like the $C_{C}^{\infty}$ functions, using Fubini. Then I tried using the density of those funtions in the $L^p$ spaces to get the result, but I couldn't finish.
More precisely, let $g_n$ be a sequence of $C_{C}^{\infty}$ functions that converge to $g$ in the $L^p$ norm, then:
$|\widehat{f\ast g}(\xi) - \widehat{f}(\xi) \widehat{g}(\xi)| \leq |\widehat{f\ast g_n}(\xi) - \widehat{f}(\xi) \widehat{g_n}(\xi)| + |\widehat{f\ast (g-g_n)}(\xi)| + |\widehat{f}(\xi) \widehat{g_n}(\xi) - \widehat{f}(\xi) \widehat{g}(\xi)|$
Where I just added and subtracted $\widehat{f}(\xi) \widehat{g_n}(\xi)$ and $\widehat{f\ast g_n}(\xi)$ and used the triangular inequality.
The first term is zero, but I cannot get rid of the other two terms. Maybe Young's inequality would be helpful, but I couldn't use it.
Edit: We only have to consider the case where $p=2$, because $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^n) + L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and in this case, we can actually take the sequence $g_k$ in the Schwartz class of functions, such that $g_k \rightarrow g$ in $L^2$ and such that $\widehat{g_k} \rightarrow \widehat{g}$ in $L^2$. Using a subsequence argument, we can assume those convergences are almost everywhere.
So, the third therm in the sum goes way, because $\widehat{f}$ is limited in $L^{\infty}$ and $\widehat{g_k} \rightarrow \widehat{g}$.

Well, as you said, let us just consider $p=2$. Let $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. First of all, we need to make sure that $f*g$ is well-defined. However, this is just an application of Young's inequality for convolutions which yields $f*g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now, we can go over to the convolution theorem. Therefore, let $(f_k)_k\subseteq L^1\cap L^2$ a sequence converging to $f$ in $L^2$ ($L^1\cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$). Then, also by Young's inequality, $f_k*g\in L^2$ and our well-known $L^1$-convolution theorem gives us $\widehat{f_k*g}=\hat{f_k}\hat{g}$. With that in mind, we follow
\begin{align*}
\|\widehat{f*g}-\hat{f}\hat{g}\|_{L^2}
&\leq \|\widehat{f*g}-\widehat{f_k*g}\|_{L^2} + \|\hat{f_k}\hat{g}-\hat{f}\hat{g}\|_{L^2}\\
&\overset{(*)}{=} \underbrace{\|(f-f_k)*g\|_{L^2}}_{\overset{\text{Young}}{\leq}\| f_k-f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2}\rightarrow 0} + \underbrace{\|(\hat{f_k}-\hat{f})\hat{g}\|_{L^2}}_{\leq\|\hat{g}\|_{L^\infty}\|\hat{f_k}-\hat{f}\|_{L^2}  \overset{(*)}{\leq} \|g\|_{L^1}\|f_k-f\|_{L^2}\rightarrow0 }\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
where in $(*)$ we used Plancherel's theorem for $L^2$-functions.
